# issue loading the ckpt file PytorchStreamReader failed reading zip archive: failed finding central directory

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, data-science-model, transfer-learning, generative-models

I am trying to load the ckpt file and getting error

`PytorchStreamReader failed reading zip archive: failed finding central directory`

Here is the code

```
import torch
import os
from torch.serialization import SourceChangeWarning

# Suppress SourceChangeWarning
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=SourceChangeWarning)

# Define the path to your checkpoint file
path = 'existing.ckpt'

if os.path.exists(path):
    try:
        # Load the checkpoint file with map_location set to "cuda"
        sd = torch.load(path, map_location="cuda")

        # Print the loaded data (checkpoint)
        print(sd)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while loading the checkpoint: {e}")
else:
    print(f"The checkpoint file '{path}' does not exist.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not getting the `the checkpoint file does not exist` error this error is most probably due to `corrupted` ckpt file or issue related to incompatibility

Check your file is a valid pytorch checkpoint format `ckpt` file. If its not correct get/download the correct one

The file could be corrupted. This is sometime when you use `wget https://<wesite>.com/<path>/existing.ckpt`. Download your file again and try

```
    sd = torch.load(path, map_location="cuda")

    # Print the loaded data (checkpoint)
    print(sd)
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes the file was corrupted. I had to run the `wget` again to get a fersh `ckpt`. It worked.